# Chinese webfont optimisation

Tags: web-fonts

For Latin-based fonts, I will download the font I want to use and run it through Fontsquirrel.com's webfont generator and subset the font accordingly. However, I'm building a Chinese site right now, and the fonts I'm using are too large to upload to Fontsquirrel. Does anyone have an approach for optimising Chinese fonts? Otherwise, I'll just have to fallback to system fonts instead.

Comment: Great question...and I don't have a specific answer but perhaps Adobe's [Type Technology](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype.html) page might give you some ideas or alternatives. You may need to use a tool like FontForge or something similar to generate your own subsets (although make sure to follow the font license permissions).

Comment: @HuiJingChen So if you pay they will increase the file size limit?

Comment: @TroyWoo Font squirrel is a free service and there is no option (at least that I know of) whereby you can pay them to increase the file size limit.

Comment: @HuiJingChen So have you tried these [alternatives](http://www.queness.com/post/14873/19-most-useful-font-face-generators-for-converting-fonts-to-web-safe-fonts)?

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Font Optimizer](https://bitbucket.org/philip/font-optimizer/overview).

Comment: Please elaborate. *Why* is this the answer to the question? Why is Font Optimizer the solution? We're looking for grounded, motivated answers. Please see the [help], specifically our [page about writing answers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info about, well, writing better answers. Thanks!